# Auto Layout ImageView Height Anchor conflicting in Collection View and not working properly

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, imageview, uicollectionviewcell

I am getting this issue where I have this image View inside a collection view cell and in the `cellForRow` configure function I am setting the height anchor of the image view depending if the model object contains image or not. If it contains image the height is 200 else it is 1. Now I am getting this error.

The error seems to fix the constraint initially and when the collection view is loaded first time, I am able to view the cells correctly. It is only once I reload the collectionview that I run into the issue of cells not showing the imageview or rather the imageview height is 1 where it should be 200. So '1' height anchor is given priority over 200 one.

```
  Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
        Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
        Try this: 
            (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
            (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600001643d40 UIView:0x7fd7fdea2ac0.height == 200   (active)>",
        "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60000165eb70 UIView:0x7fd7fdea2ac0.height == 1   (active)>"
    )
```

I have changed the priorities, but that doesn't seem to work either:

```
   if post.postMedia.isEmpty {
            cell.postMedia.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).isActive = true
            cell.postMedia.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 1).priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 999)
        }else {
            cell.postMedia.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
            cell.postMedia.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).priority = UILayoutPriority(rawValue: 1000)
        }

postMedia is the array that contains images. If it is empty the height anchor is 1 and priority is set to 999. and 200 one is given 1000. But that still doesn't work. Is there anything else I can do when two constraints are conflicting one another?
```

Kindly some help will be appreciated.

Comment: I think you are adding new constraints every time a cell is loaded.  Cells are reused, so you get multiple colliding constraints for the image height.  You should keep a reference to the height constraint in the cell, and just update its constant when you load the cell.  You could make the property optional `var heightConstraint: NSLayoutContraint?` and create one if it is `nil` when the cell is loaded, otherwise just update `heightConstraint.constant = 200` (or `1`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you are adding new constraints every time a cell is loaded. Cells are reused, so you get multiple colliding constraints for the image height. You should keep a reference to the height constraint in the cell, and just update its constant when you load the cell.

You could make the property optional:

```
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutContraint?
```

and create one if it is `nil` when the cell is loaded, otherwise just update `heightConstraint.constant = 200` (or `1`).

```
let height: CGFloat = post.postMedia.isEmpty ? 1 : 200
if cell.heightConstraint == nil {
    cell.heightConstraint = cell.postMedia.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)
    cell.heightConstraint?.isActive = true
} else {
    cell.heightConstraint.constant = height
}
```